# Events automatically detaching

Tags: c#, winforms, events, designer

When I attach a event on a control in my Windows Form I've got the problem that, after a few time, it detaches from it automatically. Let me explain, For example if I've got this line of code:

```
this.btnMainMove.MouseMove += btnMainMove_MouseMove;
```

And then I'll write the method `btnMainMove_MouseMove` in the form code, it works well for a few times but then in the designer file the line written above automatically deletes and I remain only with the method in the form code file.

This thing doesn't happen for the `Click` event but only for the methods that I create like `MouseMove`, `MoseOver`, `KeyDown`.

I'd like to know why this happens and how I could prevent this.

Thank you all!

Comment: Where did you attach the event? Is it in the Form_Load? Is there any action that you do? Can you be more specific of what `after a few time`?

Comment: Could you print the comment in the start of the file you're editing?

Comment: There's no comment at the begin of my Designer.cs. I start with the namespace and then a region with the usings, the class and so on..

Comment: @Ruly I attach the event in the InitializeComponent() method where the objects are initialized. For example I put the line that i wrote in my original post there. After that I create the method in my .cs file, inside the class and no inside another method like Form_Load. I don't do anything at that code, maybe I continue with my program and add some new features but they don't touch my original event. It's different objects with differents events. they don't work together. With 'after few time' I mean a random time, about 3-4 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designer files are generally well marked with a message like so:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18034
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The message is pretty clear. Changes can and will be lost.

These kinds of files, for instance, often have a tool that can be executed manually (using context menu options) but are most often executed automatically, after saving the accompanying `*.cs` files, compiling, etc.

Attach your events in the constructor, on load, or using the visual designer (which will track requirements based on layout files and other such things, but out of your concern).

Comment: So if I want to write my events in the .cs file i must write it in the constructor or download event? And if i have the webbrowser_DocumentCompleted event, How can I put it in the Form_Load? It has no sense.

Comment: You subscribe your event handlers in the constructor or load event, define the handler logic alongside those things, not within them, that _would_ make nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the problem but i can suggest you use lambda expressions and not the designer

```
this.btnMainMove.MouseMove += (sender,event) =>
{
    //your event logic here
};
```

but do this without clicking the event in the GUI of Visual Studio so you don't use the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing *.designer.cs file manualy?
It is good to avoid it, but you can subscribe to this event in constructor, right after InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: Thank you! I didin't know it.

Answer (score 0):

The designer makes changes only in *.Designer.cs files...

If you add the Handlers in the Constructor or the Load-Event of the form the designer won't delete your code.